How much do Americans know about Palestinians and Palestine?
According to Ynetnews:

But the huge noise of these protests obscures the truth: Most Americans aren’t antisemitic, certainly not Hamas supporters. Many of them, from the East Coast to California, don’t differentiate between Hamas and hummus.

I wonder, if there are any studies on how much Americans know about Israel and Palestine. For example:

How many Americans can point Israel on the map?
How many are aware that Gaza and West Bank are distinct territories?
Are Americans aware of the predicament of the Palestinian refugees in the larger Arab world (Lebanon, Syria, Jordan, Egypt)?
Do Americans think Israel is a democratic state, a dictatorship or a theocracy?
Do Americans know which Palestinian movements are secular, pro-democratic, renounced terror, and which have not done so?
Is there significantly greater awareness of these issues among the people with higher level of education - e.g., those who take part in protests on the University campuses?

Similar data about other countries are also of interest.
Remark
Question Which Palestinian government is getting recognized? demonstrates that some nuances may be rather confusing, and many people may genuinely have difficulty differentiating between Hamas, PA, PLO and generic "Palestinians".

Before closing for lack of focus, be aware that those questions are just examples and answers should not cover them all. So, the post has only one core question: How much do Americans know about Palestinians and Palestine?

"Do Americans think Israel is a democratic state, a dictatorship or a theocracy?" That's a bit of a misleading question, as it's objectively at least partially both the former and the latter (though I'd say more the former than the latter.) They're not strictly mutually exclusive concepts. It has pretty much all of the basic elements of a Western-style democracy, but suffrage isn't complete and the government is rather overtly Jewish and with certain rights extended more or exclusively to Jews, especially where immigration is concerned.

Are all of those examples of knowledge actually important? Even if someone can't point out the location on the map it is still possible for them to have a proper understanding of the situation. It is also possible for them to have a strong understanding of the geography of the area but have no understanding of the situation there.

@JoeW No, they're not important for uninvolved parties at all. They only start to matter if someone wishes to become involved with monetary/material donations, political pressure, or direct action. The average uninvolved American typically defers to the US State Department's stance on international matters for a baseline opinion. Just as it is largely irrelevant to know the various political groups inside Russia. Even with Hurricane Sandy, unless you were involved, it was meaningless to know the difference between the Bronx or Brooklyn in New York.

@DavidS I strongly disagree, I don’t need to be able to locate Gaza on a map to understand the situation and provide support through various organizations.

@JoeW My first comment agrees with you. In reference to this question, all of those points are largely irrelevant to the uninvolved 3rd party. One or more of those multiple points listed in the question, which may include geography, begin to become more important the more someone wishes to be and in which manner they want to be involved. So while you may not be able to point to Gaza on a map, you would have to have some understanding of the 5th point to provide support to Gaza through an organization. Geographical information is more relevant to those wanting to volunteer directly.

@DavidS I am honestly confused about what you are talking about. I was only referring to the first point as an example of knowledge that doesn't have any impact on what other knowledge a person might have. Though honestly the same can be said about the other points as well knowledge of those doesn't mean you have an actual understanding of the situation.

@reirab Jewishness isn't a religion, but an ethno-national identity (as opposed to Judaism). Even if it were, Israel showing favoritism to Jews isn't indicative of a theocracy any more than France showing preference to Catholics. In a theocracy, religion is the governing principle, as in Iran where religious authorities are given the highest power; this is not the case in Israel.

@ZevSpitz At least in American English, "Jewish" is the adjective when referring either to the religion or the ethnicity. Both usages also seemed to be common in Israel during the time I've spent there. Israel certainly isn't nearly as theocratic as countries like Iran, but it's significantly more so than most other Western-style democracies. Few governments anywhere strictly fall into one neat category. Both democracy and theocracy exist more on a continuum. Israel has significant degrees of both, though like I said before, it's more democracy than theocracy (unlike, say, Iran.)

@reirab Regarding the relation between Jewishness and nationhood see here. You are essentially adopting the anti-Zionist attitude "Jews are not people" (which is just as sickening than denying nationhood to Palestinians - see here). As for what is theocracy - your opinion is somewhat naïve. Just because the US president swears their oath of the bible or that Christian democrats are the major party in Gemrany, doesn't make these countries theocracies.

@FourLegsGoodTwoLegsBad To be clear, I was referring to the religion, not the ethnicity or national identity. I'm not sure how you think pointing out that the Israeli government has some elements of theocracy is suggesting that "Jews are not people." That's a rather ridiculous assertion (and, no, of course I am not adopting any such position.) Lots of governments have some elements of theocracy. That doesn't make either their citizens or adherents to their official or preferentially-treated religion(s) not people, nor is it really related in any way to such an assertion.

@reirab you are confusing two issues - reducing Jewishness to religion or ethnicity is denial of national identity. Theocracy has to do with the role of official religion in the government - in Israel religion and state are separated, the law of Israel is distinct from the Jewish law and supersedes it, and the religious officials do not exercise political power, except when they are also elected or appointed in non-religious political process.

@FourLegsGoodTwoLegsBad No, I'm not confusing it. You're just misreading my comments because the same adjective ("Jewish") has multiple meanings in the English language, despite me having explained which one I'm using multiple times. And, yes, as also already stated multiple times, I agree that it isn't a strict theocracy (certainly nothing to the extent of Iran,) but it does have significantly more theocratic elements than other Western-style democracies. For example, Jewish marriages within Israel can only be performed by the Orthodox Rabbinate and both partners must be Jewish.

(Or at least that was the case very recently. I know some secular political parties were trying to change some of that. I'm not sure how much success they had in that in the last few years.)

@reirab IMHO, marriage is a religious practice - it should not be a government business. In this sense Israel is more secular than most western states. It may be reasonable that a couple functioning as an economic and social unit should have certain benefits in terms of taxation, inheritance rights, etc. - theses are granted to married couples in Israel regardless of where and how they got married - a gay couple from California would be treated same as a Jewish couple from Jerusalem. And even unmarried couples can benefit, if they prove that they are a couple - quite common actually.

@FourLegsGoodTwoLegsBad I agree. The difference being that in California (or anywhere in the U.S.,) the government can't make a law that says only one sect of Jews (or Christians or Muslims, etc.) is authorized to perform Jewish (or Christian, Muslim, etc.) marriages and it must be done in a certain way according to the customs of that sect. If a an Episcopal church in Maryland wants to perform a Christian wedding for a Baptist from Alabama and a Muslim from Tunisia, they may do so, for example. Because, as you said, it's a religious practice and not the government's business.

@reirab a marriage registered officially anywhere in the world, will be recognized in Israel - doesn't matter which sect. Note that the US is also rather special in giving religious cults so much leverage - in most western states marriage is a secular ceremony with a government official. Many have a second ceremony according to their religious affiliation, but it doesn't have official value.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

While American are more knowledgable about Israel, the Palestinians, the Israel-Hamas war, and related issues than about most other foreign affairs issues, a large share of them lack even basic knowledge about the situation.
Some specific polling based answers

In a 2011 Pew Poll, only 57% of American adults could identify Israel on a map of the Middle East.

The answer from JMS to this question suggests that this may be a high end estimate. JMS notes two other surveys:

Survey: Less Than Third of American Millennials Able to Identify
Israel on Map [the actual figure is 31% of 18-29 year olds].
Only 25% of Americans can find Israel on a map [this was actually a survey of 18-24 year olds who are, on average, less knowledgable and not actually a survey of the general public].


In a March 2024 Pew Poll, 43% of American adults said that they were paying little or no attention to the Israel-Hamas war.

In a multiple choice question with four possible answers but an "I don't know" option, 35% of American adults don't know who the Prime Minister of Israel is.
20-28% of American adults didn't know anything about how or why Israel and Hamas were fighting in the current conflict, depending upon the specific question asked.

Unsurprisingly, the same poll revealed that American Jews and American Muslims (both of whom make up a very small percentage of the American public) were better informed about these matters and has strongly divergent opinions about them. About 2.3% of American adults are ethnically or religiously Jewish: 1.7% of American adults are religious Jews and about 0.6% of American adults are secular but ethnically Jewish. About 1.3% of American adults are Muslims. Overall about 3.3% of American adults are either ethnically or religiously Jewish or Muslim. See also, with county level breakdowns, the PRRI Census of American Religion (which estimates  that 2% of American adults are religiously Jewish or Muslim, but in statistics rounding to the nearest whole percentage point and with somewhat older data which matters because the Muslim population of the U.S. is growing rapidly, while the religiously Jewish population of the U.S. is slowly falling as a percentage of Americans).
The same poll reveals that young American adults know less about the conflict than older American adults:


Is there significantly greater awareness of these issues among the
people with higher level of education - e.g., those who take part in
protests on the University campuses?

As this Pew Poll chart immediately above indicates, this is definitely true.
College educated people, and particularly students at highly selective colleges and universities always know much more about almost everything we learn about through education, books, and the media, than people who are not college educated.
This is utterly unsurprising because these institutes select their students based upon whether or not they have this kind of knowledge.

A Harvard poll released on April 25, 2024 found that young adults in the U.S. don't care much about the Israel-Gaza conflict, despite the fact that this is a very hot issue on the campuses of highly selective colleges and universities. It ranks 15th out of 16 issues polled on importance to them.


The annual Harvard Youth Poll, run by the Institute of Politics (IOP)
at Harvard's Kennedy School, surveys Americans between the ages of 18-
and 29-years-old about the issues that matter most to them. This
year's poll found that young people are much closer in their concerns
to the broader electorate than media reports may suggest, with
inflation, health care and housing topping their list, followed by gun
violence.
The survey identified 16 current issues facing the U.S., asking
respondents which of two randomly paired issues most concerned them.
Inflation came out on top, with 64 percent of respondents rating it as
more important than whatever issue it was matched against. . . .
The conflict in the Middle East ranked near the bottom of young
Americans' concerns at 15th, with 34 percent of respondents choosing
it over whatever randomly selected issue it was matched against. The
only issue that ranked lower was student debt, which came in dead last
at 26 percent.


A recent Pew study reveals that Americans know very little about the boycott, divestment and sanctions (BDS) movement against Israel, which is a good gauge of knowledge of less basic Israel related political facts.


Americans have very little awareness of the boycott, divestment and
sanctions (BDS) movement against Israel – one of the most prominent
groups in the U.S. calling for boycotts of Israeli companies and
sporting, cultural and academic institutions. Only 3% of Americans
have heard “a lot” about BDS, and an additional 12% have heard “some,”
while 31% have not heard much and 53% have heard nothing at all about
the movement.

Estimates Of Answer To Other Questions
I couldn't find links to exact data on some of the other specific questions but can provide my sense based upon having seen similar polling on a variety of subjects in the past.

How many are aware that Gaza and West Bank are distinct territories?

This would definitely be a smaller percentage than the 57% of Americans who can find Israel on a map of the Middle East, but probably not a lot less, since these are frequently displayed on maps of Israel and someone who follows the news at all sees it discussed dozens of times a year. My best estimate would be about half of American adults.

Do Americans think Israel is a democratic state, a dictatorship or a
theocracy?

Americans have a very favorable view of Israel overall. Few Americans think it is a literal dictatorship.
A significant minority may think that Israel has a formally established Jewish religion, when, in fact, the Israeli state is formally secular and the constitutional identification of Israel with the Jewish people is more ethnic than religious.
The Brookings poll cited in two other answers, in which a majority of American adults had no opinion, isn't really asking the same question. It's question and the answers are as follows:


Do Americans know which Palestinian movements are secular,
pro-democratic, renounced terror, and which have not done so?

I would be very surprised if 10% of American adults knew this. My best estimate would be 2-3% of Americans who are not Jewish or Muslim would know this and that perhaps 10-15% of Jewish or Muslim Americans would know this. This is much less commonly known about American adults than knowledge about the BDS movement which is itself very uncommon.

Are Americans aware of the predicament of the Palestinian refugees in
the larger Arab world (Lebanon, Syria, Jordan, Egypt)?

This question is sufficiently vague that I don't know whether I'd qualify as knowing the answer or not, despite having far more knowledge about the issue than the average American adult with a college education.
A more specific and more factual question would be whether Americans are aware that there is a large number of Palestinian refugees in the Middle East. I would be surprised if more than 20-25% of American adults knew that fact, and that could easily be a gross over estimate. The true number could be half that.
I would be surprised if more than 5-8% of Americans both knew that there were significant numbers of Palestinian refugees in the Middle East and also had any really meaningful understanding of how their well-being compares to people who aren't Palestinian refugees in the same places. The true number could be half that.

"a survey of 18-24 year olds who are, on average, less knowledgeable" this sounds very weird to my European ears - especially for something as simple as identifying a country on a map, a 18-24 year old would still have that knowledge fresh from school here, even if they didn't follow the situation at all. Young people tend to be your best bet for "random" questionnaires about things like where countries are and what are their capital cities :D The data from the US surveys are clear enough, but it's funny. There really isn't much geography in US schools, is there?

@Luaan US education is simply more US-centric, for obvious reasons. Can you find Alabama or Guatemala on a map? I am European and I can point them within 1/4 of a continent accuracy.

Certainly those who graduated college are more knowledgeable, but those studies all seem to indicate that those currently in college are well below-average in knowledge about the situation.

I'm not really sure that I'd rate knowledge of the BDS movement as a good gauge of knowledge about current events in Israel/Palestine. That seems kind of like rating knowledge of the American Communist Party as a gauge of knowledge about economic policy. No one cares about them because it's a fringe group with extremist viewpoints (with at least a lot of overlap with anti-semitism,) not because of how much they do or don't know about the situation on the ground in Israel/Palestine. Otherwise, though, good answer.

@beirab Neither BDS nor the underlying policies and affiliation of Palestinian groups are really "current events" and neither has been reported upon in recent current event news stories.

@reirab BDS is supported by several dozen organizations and hundreds of public figures from around the world, so calling it a "fringe group" doesn't make much sense.

@fraxinus Guatemala? Sure. Alabama? Nope. But I'm not sure why that would be relevant :D We still learned about all the countries - of course we didn't learn about individual states, not even in Europe (though of course, I can point out a lot of those with particular historical relevancy in a few European countries, just like I can with some US states). Never mind that Israel is pretty closely tied with US policy, so it should be well within an US-centric education :D

@terdon The same could be said for the Communist Party. That doesn't mean they're not an extremist fringe group. (Also, that list of 'public figures' is hilarious. Personally, I recognized 5 of the names. 2 of them were musicians and the other 3 were fringe politicians/activists... so you pretty much just proved my point.)

@Luaan There is virtually zero geography in US Universities unless your major is political science, geography, or something related. 18-24 year olds are focused on their major, not general knowledge. My schooling (I'm American) only involved serious study of geography (memorizing all countries and their capitals) when I was 13. I had forgotten most of what I had learned of that by 18, although I could still tell you which continent at least 150 of the world's countries are on (including many countries that didn't exist when I was 13).

@ToddWilcox As a Comp Sci major, I did have a Human Geography class in college (in the U.S.,) but it was an option between that and something like sociology, as I recall. It was kind of funny, though, as on the first day of class, the professor handed out a world map with the borders drawn, but no labels and had everyone label as many countries as we could. Most probably got about a dozen. But there were probably 5-10 of us that were still going for probably 20-30 minutes. - haha - I think I covered pretty much everything except central Africa.

The interpretation of these questions (rather than the polling questions themselves) certainly seems to focused on what Americans no vs someone else. To differentiate between the questions "What do humans know?" and what do Americans know it would be good to include comparison against other groups. Preferably made using the same methodology. Otherwise we might not be measuring anything specific to Americans.

@ToddWilcox, in the European college model there will usually also be nothing but technical classes on the subject you studied in your non-optional part of your curriculum so you will definitely not find any geography being taught there. If you do happen to be specialized in a related topic you will probably still not get any geography. University is not meant for such fact learning education. It is meant to prepare you for research in the field and thus deeper questions than the names and locations of things.

@fraxinus Guatamala is not constantly in the news, so I don't think the comparison holds.  In the ratio of international news coverage to local population, no country comes even remotely close to Israel/Palestine, certainly not in the Western Hemisphere.

"20-28% of American adults didn't know anything about how or why Israel and Hamas were fighting in the current conflict, depending upon the specific question asked."
I'm not so sure this is a correct interpretation of the data. In the chart, those who selected "Not sure" could mean that they are ignorant of the facts, or it could mean that they are aware of the facts, but are agnostic as to whether the methods/reasons of/for fighting are valid.

The question about Israels democracy is imho pretty flawed because the baseline for many is the assertion that the US is a wonderful democracy

Pew asked Americans three basic questions about the facts of the recent Israel-Hamas War and found they were reasonably well-informed. Two-thirds of Americans got all three or two of the three correct. As you might imagine, college graduates, Jews, and Muslims were among the most aware.

The questions themselves were not exactly difficult from the perspective of, say, someone browsing a Politics StackExchange:

But I think it's worth noting that for an American, facts like "where is Palestine on a map" and the difference between Gaza and the West Bank is just not as relevant to their moral calculus as facts about who attacked who, and whether the Israeli response has been proportionate, etc.
Finally, to your specific question of:

Do Americans think Israel is a democratic state, a dictatorship or a
theocracy?

Brookings did a poll that found that for the most part, Americans answer "don't know" to whether Israel is a democracy. I'd argue though the question wording here was pretty bad and would cause people to hedge on the matter moreso than if they had simply asked if Israel was a democracy, flawed democracy, or not a democracy. (Brookings leans left).


The 1% of Americans who think that Rishi Sunak is the PM of Israel scare me. But even scarier is that if even .Barack Obama were an option, some people probably would have said that he was.

@Obie2.0, "1%" is about the number of people who will guess at random rather than admit they don't know something.

What exactly is the source for the claim that deaths have been higher among Palestinians so far?

@KarlKnechtel On November 7 The Times of Israel (not some anti colonial rag) found credible enough to relay a US official (high ranking at the State Department, a pro-colonial organization) that the official death toll is an underestimate. It was already almost 10 times the one of October 7. It's unimaginable how it could be fake to the point of today being less that October 7 https://web.archive.org/web/20240118054843/https://www.timesofisrael.com/liveblog_entry/us-official-says-gaza-death-toll-is-believed-to-possibly-be-higher-than-claimed/

@KarlKnechtel More source:Netanyahu themselves: «Netanyahu also gave his own death estimates. Some 13,000 Palestinian fighters had been killed, he said, while the civilian death rate was estimated at 1-1.5 for every combatant. That would put the total killed — fighters and civilians — at at least 26,000.» And at most 32500, compare that to the official number on March 10: 31000, so the official death toll is credible, so yeah it's more than Oct 7 WTF! https://web.archive.org/web/20240426085320/https://www.politico.eu/article/israels-netanyahu-says-he-will-defy-bidens-red-line-and-invade-rafah

@tuxayo I don't understand: why are you counting only one specific event when speaking of Israeli losses? Is this not a conflict which has been going on for quite some time? Even "the current Israeli-Hamas war" sounds to me like something older than a few months. My recollection of initial reports of Oct 7 is that it was in the context of warfare very definitely already going on.

@KarlKnechtel For what it's worth, I read "current Israeli-Hamas war" as referring to the events on and since Oct 7. Even if one goes all the way back to the beginning of Hamas, though, I find it very unlikely that more Israelis have died as a result of Israel-Hamas fighting than Palestinians. While Hamas pretty much openly states that they'd like to kill every last Israeli, the reality is that Israel's armed forces are far stronger than theirs are and it's been that way for the entirety of their existence.

@reirab As logical as that seems, it's still the sort of claim that I generally expect to be sourced.

@KarlKnechtel: In that case you could ask a question over at https://skeptics.stackexchange.com

@Obie2.0, you do realize respondents also can just not answer truthfully? Not everyone attempts to answer correctly. 1% is way lower than the "lizardman's constant" so pretty meaningless.

"lizardman's constant": https://slatestarcodex.com/2013/04/12/noisy-poll-results-and-reptilian-muslim-climatologists-from-mars/

This is empirical based on reading / watching multiple new sources, polls, etc.
Please keep in mind that my personal opinion is that long-term a two state solution will likely happen. It will likely need the next generation to accomplish it. IMHO.
Most americans most likely don't know and likely don't actually care that much. This isn't intended to sound uncaring, but an observation.
Many Americans are comfortable enough having their leaders and percieved leaders tell them what to think:
Example: https://www.cbsnews.com/news/shawn-fain-uaw-face-the-nation-transcript-01-28-2024/
The president of the UAW bringing up the move of the US Embassy in Israel and "other things" during the last administration as negatives. This includes the Abraham Accords.
Younger people are comfortable steaming ahead without being fully informed or accepted highly partisan info as "the truth".
If accepting that "the truth" means eliminating Israel, the only democracy in the Middle East, the same Americans likely would say "hold on a minute".
Most americans likely can't imagine the environment that many countries consider normal. Coups, political arrests, morality police, factions in armed conflicts.
Other concepts that are normal day to day in West bank that Americans likely couldn't fathom are the political and educational systems. For example: The Martyrdom payments (Pay for Slay), how many Americans would accept that their tax dollars have ended up going to that?
EDIT:
In my work, I deal with some very smart people in documenting their systems. For years I've been amazed at how much they can suggest two conflicting options. That leaves me to have to walk through with them what they asked for and having to explain that they can't have it both ways.
How does this apply? If a poll asked "Do you think the Pals should get what they are asking for?" and "Does Israel have a right to exist?" What percentage of people will answer yes to both?

This answer is empirical ? or it is base on what you feel is the truth ?

@Bougainville  That is a good question. I try very hard to be honest with myself. It is what I have observed, but I am not a fulltime pollster or newsperson. The polls cited in the other answers don't ask questions below the very top level. That is fine, but each each question that "I don't know" would have been the response is likely missing meanful data. Your thoughts?

I think saying "general public is generally uninformed" will be true for any issue, but when it comes to polarizing issues there's also a lot of misinformation, not just lack of.

@littleadv That goes hand-in-hand with how loud/funded/organized/determined/etc. an involved group is. A WSJ Op-Ed 4/22 has well-cited examples of how the current protests are being feed by terrorist groups.

What does either the Union of American Women or United Auto Workers or whatever UAW is have to do with Israel or Palestine?  Do they have local sections there?

@gerrit I can only assume you didn't watch the provided link or either your question is why he is saying anti-Israel views as the leader and spokesperson of  ~400,000 active and ~600,000 retired members. He said these views as why one US president is better than another. So, yes IMO it is a valid concern. It certainly goes to, in many cases, people just letting their leaders telling them what to think on a given subject. None of his views on the middle east have anything to do with wages / benefits for US auto workers. Do they?

How many Americans can point Israel on the map?


How many are aware that Gaza and West Bank are distinct territories?



Survey: Less Than Third of American Millennials Able to Identify Israel on Map
Only 25% of Americans can find Israel on a map



Are Americans aware of the predicament of the Palestinian refugees in the  larger Arab world (Lebanon, Syria, Jordan, Egypt)?


Could find no polls.


Do Americans think Israel is a democratic state, a dictatorship or a theocracy?


April 2023 Poll

7% A state with restricted minority rights
9% A vibrant democracy
13% A flawed democracy
13% A state with segregation similar to apartheid
56% I don't know

Empirically: Most Americans don't know.  And while Israel almost became a dictatorship earlier this year (Netanyahu's attempt to nullify Israel's judicial branch, the only check on executive power in Israel), it is actually closer to a theocracy.  A country established and maintained along religious grounds.


Do Americans know which Palestinian movements are secular, pro-democratic, renounced terror, and which have not done so?


I could find no polls, but I would think not.
Jimmy Carter in his 2006 book "Peace not Apartheid", lamented that he was the last American government official who had met with all the players in the middle east including Hamas and Hezbollah leaders. (Jimmy Carter retired from government nearly 50 years ago). Given America bans on government officials meeting with these groups.  In this book Jimmy Carter stated that the US state department didn't even understand these groups positions on issues like whether they would support a peace agreement between the Palestinian People and the Israelis.
This is a long trend of US diplomats in general which from much of the 1970's and 1980's refused any contact with the PLO when it was the primary representative of the Palestinian people.  I remember the US lead diplomat to the United Nations, Andrew Young was forced to resign from office in 1979 after holding a meeting with the PLO observer to the United Nations in New York.


Is there significantly greater awareness of these issues among the people with higher level of education - e.g., those who take part in protests on the University campuses?


I could find no polls from the protesters, In general educated people of any age have a greater knowledge of the issues; but that's mostly because the prevalent knowledge is so low.  Even educated people in the United States generally have a pathetic understanding of the historic much less contemporary Middle East troubles.

I think Americans and the young protesters are more aware of the huge casualties in the current Gaza troubles.  Aware of the 35,000 deaths, mostly women and children.  Aware that the United States weapons and finances are being used to perpetrate these acts. Aware that the 35,000 deaths is a very conservative number.  That is primarily what they are reacting too.

It's become a significant issue for President Joe Biden's 2024 Presidential Campaign when in late Feb about two months ago 13% of democratic voters in the Michigan Democratic Primary voted uncommitted for the Presidential Candidate in protest over Biden's performance in the Israeli Gaza troubles.  That's huge as Michigan is an important battleground state for President Biden, and the presidential race is very tight.



A NatGeo survey is interesting reading although possibly dated. The 25% figure for Israel is not too bad given that 65% could not locate France and 11% cannot even find their own country.

"it is actually closer to a theocracy. A country established and maintained along religious grounds." The state of Israel is formally secular, does not afford religious official a formal role in government (although some political parties in Israel are expressly religious) and describes and implements the state's Jewish nationalism on an ethnic rather than religious basis. It is not a theocracy, which would be rule by religious officials as is the case in Iran.

@ohwilleke that is correct to a point, there's some religious involvement in government, but it's not a theocracy. For example, family law is based on religion - but not a single religion, rather all marriages have to be done in conformance to the religion of the couple (whichever that is). Similarly, official holidays are mostly Jewish religious holidays (except for the Independence Day), but the same law defining them also guarantees freedom of celebrating holidays of other religions.

@littleadv FWIW, India takes the same approach to family law.

Re meetings with PLO and such - since the Oslo accords there's definitely no such prohibition. Israel was also able to reach agreements with Lebanon (where Hizbullah is deeply rooted in power and is part of the government), which were official, signed and ratified by both sides.

@littleadv,  True that, the Oslo accords were in 1993,  Then in 1994 the PLO morphed into the Palestinian Authority.  Today the U.S. Administration has similar rules not to speak to Hamas and Hezbollah,  which I think were Jimmy's point.

When I was a kid, I used to call Israel a theocracy on the basis of their law on divorce, Haredi Jews serving in the military, and a few other things. I still might joke that it is, because those laws are definitely religiously discriminatory, but the same is true of plenty of other countries (UK with its Lords Spiritual, all the countries with official religions...). I now think a theocracy has to actually have the religious leaders as one of the practical heads of government, which only leaves a few: Iran, Vatican City, Andorra and Bhutan.

@Obie2.0 theocracy is a country which laws are based on the dominant religion. E.g.: most muslim countries (but especially Iran and Saudi Arabia), some Catholic countries (e.g.: Philippines), etc. Israeli family laws are not a sign of theocracy, they're a sign of conservatism: they require couples to be of the same religion (whatever it may be), and handle their marital affairs through that religion's process. There's now a civil divorce, but still no civil marriage. Haredi Jews are actually not serving in the military, which is a different problem.

No, I would say that does not qualify. A high religious country will make laws highly influenced by their religious culture (against abortion or same-sex marriage, for instance). But that does not mean that the church directly controls the state, which is theocracy. If the Pope changes the law, then the law of Vatican City changes–but not the law of the Philippines. If the Ayatollah changes the law, then the law of Iran changes—but not the law of Iraq or Bahrain.

A theocracy is a country established and maintained along religious grounds, hard stop.  There is no equivalent to any modern country with Israel on these grounds.

@JMS - That's quite the head-spinning assertion! Let's grant your definition for the sake of argument, even though I already mentioned mine, which happens to be the standard one. The first example of a country that has more religion in government than Israel is Vatican City, a UN observer state—one of two along with Palestine—whose absolute monarch is a religious leader and whose population consists almost entirely not just of members of that religion, but of priests.

The second example that comes to mind is Iran, whose Supreme Leader is a cleric and whose law is much more religiously influenced. By contrast, Israel's PM is not a rabbi, and the law, while religiously discriminatory, is not as completely and explicitly shaped by it in countless details as the sharia code of Iran. So there are at least two countries that are maintained along religious grounds to, in my view, a greater extent than Israel. Andorra also deserves a mention for one of its two princes always being a bishop, though it is otherwise rather secular.

This answer is a little opinionated in some interpretations. BTW, the controversies surrounding the status of Haredi Jews are probably more significant than family law. https://www.yahoo.com/news/military-exemptions-ultra-orthodox-divide-170826418.html I wouldn't say such issues are not found elsewhere in some way (conscientious objectors etc.)  but there's probably not such a large proportion elsewhere as in Israel. There's also the issue of how influential they are https://slate.com/news-and-politics/2024/04/israel-gaza-war-netanyahu-orthodox-yeshiva-military.html
